# Cakephp - Testing Components - cannot find component

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I am writing a component test in cakephp
here is my code

```
<?php
  class PermissionTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
   var $fixtures = array('Org');  
   function testsetPermission() { 
      $this->PermissionComponentTest = new PermissionComponent(); <---- line 5
```

I get this error - Fatal error: Class 'PermissionComponent' not found in /Sites/php/cake/Demo_Code/perm/app/tests/cases/components/permission.test.php on line 5

Why is it looking for the component in tests/cases ? 
Also I tried moving the component into this directory and it didnt work.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the component manually with App::import():

```
App::import('Component', 'Permission');
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked! I tried, var $components = array('Permission');